# Spring Data REST does not seem to be working with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to use Spring Data REST for elasticsearch. The built-in REST controller for POST doesn't seem to be working: I am getting an error when I attempt to post a document. The issue is easy to reproduce:
I created a simple entity:

```
@Document(indexName = "user", type = "user", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
    private String firstName;

     @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
    private String lastName;
    // getters and setters are skipped
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, String> {
}
```

When I try to get all users I am getting the response:

```
 curl -X GET "http://localhost:9000/users"
 {
  "_links" : {
   "self" : {
   "href" : "http://localhost:9000/users{?page,size,sort}",
   "templated" : true
},
"search" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:9000/users/search"
}
},
 "page" : {
 "size" : 20,
 "totalElements" : 0,
 "totalPages" : 0,
 "number" : 0
 }
}
```

but when I am trying to add a user:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:9000/users -d '{"id":"4e9e62aa-7312-42ed-b8e4-24332d7973cd","firstName":"test","lastName":"test"}'
```

I am getting an error:

```
{"cause":null,"message":"PersistentEntity must not be null!"}
```

There seems to be a Jira ticket opened for this issue without any comments:
[Jira Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-137)

I am wondering if it is possible to avoid writing CRUD REST controllers for Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 4):

The workaround is to add

```
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = RestElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

annotation to the application class where RestElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean is defined as

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public  class RestElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean
    extends org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        setMappingContext(new org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext());
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the maximum version of spring-data-elasticsearch this works with?